# When did Panda Bear Guy die?

Tags: starcraft

The Panda Bear Guy critter is a running gag in Starcraft commentary. He died in [a match on Andromeda](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdfPsKWyQik) casted by Tasteless. Which match was it?

Comment: Could we have a little more context?

Comment: @Juan: What kind of context are you looking for? It's an anthropomorphized critter that appears on some maps. The clip that I linked to shows him, and I wanted to know which match the clip was from.

Comment: Well, that clears it a little. Also, I thought he died for ever... but those critters respawn, right?

Comment: @Juan: He was back in the next match. Don't worry. Critters don't respawn during a match, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AzAng - 김국군 [ Kim Guk Kun] (T) vs 815 - 배병우 [ Bae Byung Woo] (Z)
GOM Clasic Season 2

Comment: For future visitors: [the game on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBRt4GzoTow). Please skip 5 min in if you watch it! That way you won't have to endure Tasteless's "Oh, there's Panda Bear Guy, I like him", which is so sad when you know how it's going to end.